# how to change the page number to A-1 in word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I am doing my appendix for thesis. I need to include the appendix and I have already done section breaks.The page numbers for the appendix should go like A,A-1,A-2,A-3 and B-1,B-2,B-3 so on. I can't seem to to be able to do even after the section breaks.it seem that when i change the page above, the one below gets affected. not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem with the second response is that if you are creating a table of contents from the reference tab, the A and B part of the page numbers will not populate in the TOC. If you are brave, you can create a macro. Here are some instructions that I copied from http://word.mvps.org/faqs/numbering/pagenumbering.htm and have used myself. It will create a macro in your document for custom page numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your page numbers are on a footer (or header), it seems that Word makes them "same as above by" default. Thus numbering goes across sections.

Activate your footer, look if there is a tab "same as above" on it. There is a button on a ribbon which removes that. After that your fields on a footer will be independent.

Comment: I am still not able to do it.... u mean link to previous?

Answer (score 0):

By default Word copies headers and footers from the previous section. To change the headers and footers in a section, double-click its header or footer.

In *Header & Footer Tools*, make sure *Link to Previous* is not selected in *Navigation* group. (Word 2010 displays *Same as Previous* near the header/footer area if *Link to Previous* is selected.) Then type `A-` before the page number.

To start numbering from 1 in the section, click *Page Number* button in the *Header & Footer* group, and then click *Format Page Numbers*. In *Page Number Format* dialog, select *Start at* (instead of *Continue from previous section*), and enter `1` into the edit box. Click *OK* to confirm.

Now the page numbers should display as *A-1*, *A-2*…

Repeat the steps above for section with Appendix B.